# Custom Window Appearance Python

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, tkinter, appearance

I have attempted to do research on this subject but I have been unable to find anything because I don't really know how to phrase my questions. I am just starting to make a Python application and the first thing that I want to get straight is appearance. For the appearance of the program, I want to have my own custom close button, maximize button, minimize button, and bar at the top as I have done in the past with Expression Blend. How can I do this with Python, and what graphics library(Tkinter, etc.) should I use? Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking around and I think that it might be good to do this in PyQT. What do you guys think?

Comment: It depends on what are you doing your application for. From what I know PyQT and wxPython are udner different licenses for example. If that is not an issue it depends on how complex it would be. Custom buttons and the like can be done also on Tkinter and that would have an advantage of being part of python distribution. But if you would want to integrate something like OpenGL or matplotlib etc. you would be better off with wxPython or PyQt. I would recommend wxPython as they have a very active mailing list in case you run into troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) for a start, it's widely used.

If you're interested in Qt, check out both [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) and [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).

If you're talking about Windows only, rather than cross platform, consider [PyWin32](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyWin32) to use the Windows APIs directly instead of through one of the other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Guy what you want to do is remove the default window frame and create yours. You can use "thewindow".overideredirect(True) to remove the window's frame then you create a similar functioning title bar with tkinter

Visit https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Ds0cpxPSN4k4&ved=2ahUKEwi4y6ae0Pn5AhUbxAIHHcZcDRUQwqsBegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3TQ9WwdeZ5NltaQgaA2K6w
for more information

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32639233)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).